# How to reuse analog TV - small Sony in particular

Tags: analog, tv

SOLVED SOLVED
SOLVED SOLVED
Min of 30 characters required

Comment: Hi! To me, it's not quite clear what you ask here – ["composite video"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video) is really just a TV channel in baseband. So, there's nothing to generate – your "normal" analog TV channel *is* already composite video, on a given carrier frequency. So, what's the technical question here? I'd love to give a specific question, but I'm not sure what can be said that wikipedia did not already say?

Comment: Maybe he wants to convert from DTV (ATSC?) to the old analog (NTSC) format?  Or to composite video?

Comment: You can convert a composite video signal to RF with a RF video modulator. But what composite you want and from which source?

Comment: Channel number may not matter (to you), but the source of your video signal matters very much. Is is Analog or Digital? If it's analog, is it composite (NTSC/PAL/...) or component (RGB/VGA/...). If it's digital, is a reasonably modern standard like HDMI or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can buy a new video-to-NTSC modulator, e.g., this [US$22 unit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NV9SXCM) for channels 3 & 4, or you can browse flea markets and used goods stores for one, likely a dollar or two. The [video signal standards](https://thebroadcastknowledge.com/2020/01/10/video-what-is-525-line-analog-video/) are NTSC (525 line, 30 full frames per second) for North America, and PAL (625 line, 25 full fps) for much of the rest of the world.

Find an old video recorder, [iconoscope camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconoscope) or [camcorder](https://www.ebay.com/itm/166196953991?epid=108928954) or game and enjoy!

Comment: Technically, NTSC and PAL are just colour encoding systems. Both NTSC and PAL have been used with both 60 Hz 525i and 50 Hz 625i scanning systems.

Comment: No, I did not ask for description of various TV signals. I am looking for a way to convert another signal ( and I am not sayong ewhat singnal since I do no need another desritiption oif it ) to NTSC singnal . I can figure out the actual; conversion , but I was and still lookiing for a way to GENRATE the NTSC signal.